# Property of some determinant

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that 
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
1+a^2-b^2 & 2b & -2b \\
2ab & 1-a^2+b^2 & 2a\\
2b & -2a^2 & 1-a^2-b^2\\
\end{vmatrix}
$$     is a perfect cube.

Comment: Wat have you tried so far? And what are $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Do you know the rules of Sarrus?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner yes, but I’m trying to find a shortcut without expanding

Comment: @HSN a and b are any variables.... I tried some row operations to see if I can simplify it.. but unable to figure out how to solve without expanding

Answer (score 2):

The claim is not true. For $a=-1$ and $b=2$ the determinant is $-24$, which is not a perfect cube. The matrix then equals
$$
\begin{pmatrix} -2 & 4 & -4 \cr -4 & 4 & -2 \cr 4 & -2 & -4\end{pmatrix}
$$

There might be a typo in the given matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1+a^2-b^2 & 2b & -2b \\
2ab & 1-a^2+b^2 & 2a\\
2b & -2a^2 & 1-a^2-b^2\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$